# Set-PrintConfiguration Acces deny

Tags: powershell

Two PCs are connected with Remote Desktop to a Windows Server 2019 in the cloud, executing the script below to modify the configuration of a printer, everything executes without error until "Set-PrintConfiguration" is executed, which gives the error that is commented, Any idea why the error? How could I avoid it?

thanks a lot

```
$ComputerName=$env:computername
$PrinterName ="My printer Name"
$PrintConfiguration = Get-PrintConfiguration -ComputerName $ComputerName -PrinterName $PrinterName
$PrintTicketXML =[xml]$PrintConfiguration.PrintTicketXML
$UpdatedPrintTicketXML=$PrintConfiguration.PrintTicketXML -replace 'Landscape','Portrait'
$PrintConfiguration.PaperSize = "A6"
#Now the error
Set-PrintConfiguration -ComputerName $ComputerName -printername $PrinterName -PrintTicketXML $UpdatedPrintTicketXML


<#
PS C:\Users\Jorge> C:\Users\Public\Documents\Sin título2.ps1
Set-PrintConfiguration : Acceso denegado al recurso especificado.
En C:\Users\Public\Documents\Sin título2.ps1: 8 Carácter: 1
+ Set-PrintConfiguration -ComputerName $ComputerName -printername $Prin ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (MSFT_PrinterConfiguration:ROOT/StandardCi...erConfiguration) [Set-PrintConfiguration], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Set-PrintConfiguration
#>
```

Comment: Have you tried running the script as a user that has admin privileges on the other computer?

Comment: yes, I tried with the Windows session open with a user who is a member of the Administrators group and opening PowerShell ISE with administrator rights (right click and "open as administrator"), but the problem is not fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to grant that user CIM / WMI permissions, to add the printer.

```
net localgroup WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__ /add "domain\user"
```

Test your access

````
$ComputerName = $env:computername
$CimOption = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol Dcom
$CimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -SessionOption $CimOption

Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem -CimSession $CimSession```
````